# What do I need to pass to the Image class as the first parameter?

Tags: 8, media

I'd like to use the Image API directly to perform few simple operations with images (I'm aware of image styles and for various reasons I would prefer to not use image styles for the application I'm working on). The trouble I'm having is what I need to pass to the Image class as the first parameter. The constructor of the Image class expects an `ImageToolkitInterface $toolkit` as the first parameter. I'm not sure what to plug in for it.

Hunting around the forums, I see people have used `\Drupal::service('image.toolkit')` to pass in as the first parameter however this isn't working for me.

Here is a snippet of one of the operations I'm attempting to perform. Feel free to pan my whole approach.

```
use Drupal\Core\Controller\ControllerBase;    
use Drupal\Core\Image\Image;

class myImageController extends ControllerBase { 

  public function imageHeight() {

    $image_path = 'public://path/to/image.jpg';

    $image = new Image(\Drupal::service('image.toolkit'), $image_path);

    $image_height = $image->getHeight();

    ksm([$image_height]);

    return [

      '#markup' => $this->t('Did this work?'),
    ];     
  }  
}
```

Does anyone know what I should use to pass in as the first parameter? I'm only using the default GD2 Image toolkit. Also, I'm on Drupal 8.6. Thanks!

Comment: `$image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($image_path);`?

Comment: I like cchen's thinking. But, if you want to keep going with your current course, I'm not seeing an `image.toolkit` service, but I'm seeing an `image.toolkit.manager` service (https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21core.services.yml/service/image.toolkit.manager/8.6.x) - maybe that's what you want, or can use

Comment: Thanks cchen, your suggestion did the trick. Also, I tried the `image.toolkit.manager` but unfortunately that didn't work, thanks though for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$image = \Drupal::service('image.factory')->get($image_path);
```

[See the whole usage](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Image!ImageFactory.php/function/ImageFactory%3A%3Aget/8.2.x)